# creating rss feed from a datasource using asp.net rss toolkit

Tags: asp.net, rss

Did anyone create an rss feed using the following toolkit http://www.codeplex.com/ASPNETRSSToolkit

I have a datasource that i can assign, which should give me an rss link.

for e.g. i am trying to create an rss feed for this url  [http://webclip.in](http://webclip.in/user.aspx?u=vamsi)

Answer (score 0):

Yes I had tried to create an RSS feed using the toolkit. Generally straightforward but to make it compatible with most browsers, you need some tweakings. This thread might help:
http://aspnetrsstoolkit.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=12179

There are sample codes in the toolkit so I will not provide any here.